# Return NSArray in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

How can I return the array that is being filled in the completion block? It is some JSON being parsed into an array of objects.

```
-(NSArray *)GetMapVehiclePoints
{
    NSString *methodURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@GetMapVehiclePoints", BASE_URL];
   __block NSArray *parsedVehicles = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:methodURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSArray *vehicles = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        parsedVehicles = [self parseVehicles:vehicles];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    return parsedVehicles;
}
```

Every time I return this method I get an empty array because the completion block hasn't ran yet. How can I return the array inside of the block?

Answer (score 1):

`getMapVehiclePoints` can't/shouldn't return an array. Use a callback block instead...

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id value);

- (void)getMapVehiclePointsWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback {
    NSString *methodURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@GetMapVehiclePoints", BASE_URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:methodURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (callback) callback([self parseVehicles:(id)responseObject]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        if (callback) callback(@[]);
    }];
}
```

---

```
[self getMapVehiclePointsWithCallback:^(NSArray *vehiclePoints) {
    NSLog(@"%@", vehiclePoints);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pass is a completion block for the method

```
- (void)GetMapVehiclePointsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *points))completion;
```